# Convert to first order ODE in order to describe velocity and evolution of time of the location of the m mass body. Newton's grravitational law

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to convert the [equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cam22.png) to first order ODE. I want to describe velocity and evolution of time of the location of the mass $m$ body. The equation shall be solved so it can be used for Runge-Kutta methods.

Here is the Newton's gravitational law equation i want to convert:

$$m \frac {d^2}{dt^2}\pmatrix{x\\y} = -\frac {GmM}{(x^2+y^2)^ \frac {3}{2}}\pmatrix{x\\y} $$

so far I tried this approach

$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\pmatrix{x\\y}  = \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{dv}{dr} \frac{dr}{dt} = v\frac{dv}{dr}$$

Does this describe the velocity well enough? How can I describe evolution of time?

Can assume that $M>>m$

Thanks!

Comment: You can convert this second order ODE to a system of first order ODE using `v_x = dx/dt` and `m dv_x/dt = ...`, and similarly for y.  Perhaps what you are looking for

Comment: See tag [tag:celestial-mechanics] and on stackoverflow [a similar search result](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Borbital-mechanics%5D+rk4)